# How das GCP Dataflow handle failures when reading from a Spanner Datastream?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-spanner

I have a Dataflow pipeline (stream) that reads from a Cloud Spanner Change Stream.

**What happens if the Dataflow pipeline fails?**

Will it lose all currently in-progress data, or is data read & processed only ack-ed once it's successfully processed and as long the data did not exceed the retention period set on the Change Stream?

Would it be correct to state

> As long as data is not older than the retention period on the data stream, and a Dataflow pipeline can recover, it'll eventually be processed.

If the above is incorrect, how do Dataflow and Spanner handle this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

I think your statement is correct. In general, for Dataflow, when running in streaming mode, a bundle including a failing item is retried indefinitely, which might cause your pipeline to permanently stall (https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/common-errors).